# R ggplot2 geom_jitter: plotting all zeros

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, jitter

In R ggplot2, when I plot all zeros and use geom_jitter(), some variations are automatically added to zeros. How can I undo that? I still want all points at 0 y axis.

```
y = rep(0,100)

x = rep(c("A","B","C","D"),25)

D = data.frame(x,y)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(D,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter()
```

[image]

Comment: Umm...don't use `+ geom_jitter()`? Just use, `ggplot(D,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_boxplot()`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns But I do need it to spread the dots horizontally...

Comment: then use `geom_jitter(height = 0)` - this forces the vertical variation/jitter to zero, but still allows the points to jitter horizontally.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to keep the dots and spread them horizontally, you can use `geom_jitter(height = 0)`. This will force the vertical variation/jitter to zero, but still allows the points to "jitter" horizontally.

```
ggplot(D, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_jitter(height = 0)
```

Comment: The editors of ggplot could make geom_jitter so that the dots distribute evenly, instead of randomly. Despite my jitter, I still have points that overlap...